# Is there a way to hide ubuntu dock and top bar using terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, top-bar

I want a shortcut to hide the top bar and dock, so I thought the best way to do that would be to figure out a terminal command which does the same.So, can someone tell me the command to do so or another way to make the shortcut work?

Comment: The quick method is to toggle fullscreen (of the window in focus) with `F11`.

Comment: @PRATAP I don't know what gnome-shells-dock is but I'm just using the default ubuntu setup. I haven't installed dock extensions and stuff

Comment: @sudodus I know about that but some applications like nautilus won't go fullscreen with `F11`. You can use `Ctrl+Super+M` to make them fullscreen but I don't want to make every application fullscreen one by one.

Comment: Nah, I'm dock is the normal dock (Its's probably Ubuntu Dock I suppose). As I told you I haven't installed any extension to make the dock like that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This command can be used to hide the topbar

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.actor.hide();'
```

to show it back

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.actor.show();'
```

You can tweak the commands with a script to toggle show and hide.

---

For Ubuntu dock hiding - the below workaround is a bit overkill because we are disabling the whole extension.

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell.Extensions --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions --method org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.DisableExtension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

for enabling back

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell.Extensions --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions --method org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.EnableExtension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

You can tweak the commands with a script to toggle Enabling and Disabling

All together, you can have a single keyboard shortcut that can toggle "Hiding the Topbar and disabling the Extension" "Showing the Topbar and Enabling the Extension"

You can create a script with below content.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

status1=$(gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.actor.visible;')
status2=$(gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell.Extensions --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions --method org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.GetExtensionInfo ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com | grep "'state': <2.0>" >/dev/null && echo "OFF" || echo "ON")

if [ "$status1" == "(true, 'false')" ]; then
  gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.panel.actor.show();'
else
  gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.panel.actor.hide();'
fi

if [ "$status2" == "ON" ]; then
  gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell.Extensions --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions --method org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.DisableExtension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
else
  gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell.Extensions --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions --method org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.EnableExtension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
fi
```

Below GIF shows the result. **However, when gnome-shell refreshes/re-login/reboot etc. will affect the persistence.**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: +1 worked up until 20.04.  Now hiding the panel just returns `(false, '')`, same with trying to show.  Does anyone know why?